# Parse.com File saving Android not working

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I modeled my code after their Mealspotting tutorial but for some reason, I can't see the file saved in the Data Browser. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
private void saveScaledPhoto(byte[] data) {

        // Resize photo from camera byte array
        Bitmap snypImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        Bitmap snypImageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(snypImage, 200, 200
                * snypImage.getHeight() / snypImage.getWidth(), false);

        // Override Android default landscape orientation and save portrait
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedScaledMealImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(snypImageScaled, 0,
                0, snypImageScaled.getWidth(), snypImageScaled.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rotatedScaledMealImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

        byte[] scaledData = bos.toByteArray();

        // Save the scaled image to Parse
        photoFile = new ParseFile("snyp.jpg", scaledData);
        photoFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("photo",photoFile);
                    Log.d("save status",photoFile.getName() + " is saved!");
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's not in the File Storage either

Comment: How did you save the image file? Could you post the code?

Comment: "ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("photo",photoFile);

Comment: Here's a huge example on saving images to Parse.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23859786/294884  The thing I'm struggling with the getting the damned bitmap from the camera onActivityResult !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just forgetting to save your User object: `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();`

Comment: why is it saveEventually() and not saveInBackground()?

Comment: also, can I still retrieve the files from the User without creating a Photo class?

Comment: Just because it's simpler. saveEventually will save your photo, eventually (as soon as it can) :)

Comment: Thanks, can you answer my second question too?

Comment: Yes, you can. In this case you'll need to create a field for the photo on the user class and associate it to the user object and save it, the same way as the "Photo" class. Are you saving a profile picture?

Comment: No I'm saving all the photos the user takes and eventually the plan is to display all those photos in a gallery on a  different activity.

Comment: what do you mean associate it to the user object? am I not already doing that?

Comment: Sorry. Did not noticed. You are. You are just forgetting to save the user object. `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();` In thin case, the photo will be edited everytime you save it. If you want something like an album you should use an array with: `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().add("photos", photo); ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveEventually();`

Comment: One more question, how do I retrieve the array if i do ParseUser.getCurrentUser().add("photos,photo); I tried getList("photos) but that returned null.

Comment: @user3140562 There is an issue when trying to get a list of ParseFile described here: [link](https://parse.com/questions/how-to-get-a-parsefile-from-jsonarray-retrieved-from-cloudcode-in-android) I would try with JSONArray `ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONArray("photos")`, and then, iterate over it and access the url of the photo from each JSONObject.